# iOS: Notification Center - What's the max length?

Tags: ios, push

I am sending a push notification to our app. I would like to know the max length of characters that can be shown when you pull down the notification center (I know that the payload is up to 256 bytes, but characters seem to be truncated after a certain number of characters. Also, I know the AlertView can have up to 107 characters. I am asking for the limit in the notification center).

Comment: As you said the payload is 256 bytes, so it depends how you build your payload. The simple way to know your case is count on the characters in your truncated example, then you know that's the max length in your case. If other fields are variable, you need to reserve some space for them. Normally, you need to estimate the worst case of the non-message fields.

Answer (score 2):

Other way to go around of this limit, this is are using a

**loc-key**

**loc-args**

features of APNS.

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9) at **Localized Formatted Strings** block